# How to show rows from multiple tables that contain a specific value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables `MD` and `Fuji` both tables have a `Date` and `Time` column. I would like to have a way to search for a specific value in either `Date` and/or `Time` in both tables and then show the rows from both tables that contain the specific value

Comment: your resultset has to have a fix number and type of columns. is there a common structure both these tables share?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 0):

UNION is what you're looking for. You can go with :

```
SELECT Date, Time FROM MD WHERE MD.Date = ? OR MD.Time = ?
UNION ALL
SELECT Date, Time FROM Fuji WHERE Fuji.Date = ? OR Fuji.Time = ?;
```

`?` being your search value. Columns count has to be the same, and columns has to be in the same order though.

If your column count doesn't match, a fix is to fill missing values with null, like :

```
SELECT Date, Time, column3 FROM MD WHERE MD.Date = ? OR MD.Time = ?
UNION ALL
SELECT Date, Time, null as column3 FROM Fuji WHERE Fuji.Date = ? OR Fuji.Time = ?;
```

You can even have filling null value in both table, like :

```
SELECT null as column0, Date, Time, column3 FROM MD WHERE MD.Date = ? OR MD.Time = ?
UNION ALL
SELECT column0, Date, Time, null as column3 FROM Fuji WHERE Fuji.Date = ? OR Fuji.Time = ?;
```